# execute scheduled task in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, scheduled-tasks

I have a requirment to build a small utility, which fires a sql query to fetch a list of user email addresses and send emails to them scheduled to be executed daily.

I was wondering what may be a good way to perform this in .net

I am working on VS2010 premium, c# 4.0

Comment: Your best bet is to schedule the task directly on the database server using SQL Agent (I'm assuming an MS stack here and SQL Server).

Comment: For the email look at using SMTP System.Net.Mail for the Query look at creating a Stored Procedure that your Service works against, for the actual Windows Service.. you can do this via .dll or Console Application. you will have 3 basic components to your Application. if you are doing this as a .EXE look at System.Diagnostics and Process and ProcessInfo Classes.. if your Database handles Emails / Sending emails you can do all of this in once location by creating a few database scripts, Packages ect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends by your requirements.

I think you could create a console application that encapsulate this behavior then you can schedule the task using windows schedule task

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and have it execute your program once a day.

An alternative may be to write a service that waits until a certain time in a day and runs this simple task, but this seems a little too heavy-handed unless you have more plans for this service in the future.  (So, for example, you want the service to be able to send emails, do some database maintenance, listen on some port, etc.)

Having a application run full-time in the background for such a simple task doesn't *seem* like a good way to go about it.  There are too many ways to stop an application.

Answer (score 2):

Write the application in whatever language or platform you want and then use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make the application run according to your schedule.

That way, you can focus your application on its core thing (fetching stuff, sending emails) and let Microsoft worry about the details of creating a robust scheduling service.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [nice example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx) to write scheduled tasks in .NET

Answer (score 1):

.Net would be just fine for this. I suggest writing a console application to do what you require, and using [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to run your application at your chosen interval.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to write it in .net?

If yes, then go for the task scheduler like already suggested. If not, then you could also create a job in the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this emailing procedure in web environment(ASP.Net), you can use [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/) scheduling service. A [.Net library](http://atrigger.com/docs/wiki/13/library-net) is also available to create scheduled tasks without overhead.

**Disclaimer: I'm among their team.**